# GRASS unable to download any extension from GRASS Addons

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, kriging, add-ons

I'm trying to install some add-ons to GRASS, but each time I try to download an addon, I'm getting the same error:

```
g.extension.py extension=v.autokrige svnurl=http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <v.autokrige>...
ERROR: GRASS Addons <v.autokrige> not found
(Fri Feb 05 11:29:55 2016) Command finished (1 sec)
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Any change to update to GRASS GIS 7? We released the stable 7 more than a year ago, after years of development... it is worth it!